# How to make the output data (product description) line by line in the online shopping website?

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm helping a client put their product on the 11 street online shopping cart, but I am facing a problem when I succeed at inserting `product_short_description` on the 11 street online shopping page - it is showing me the strings combined together. How can I make the strings of `product_short_description` display on two lines, one above the other?

My code is shown below:

```
<?php


include '../db_config/db_conn.php';

$sql = 'SELECT c1.entity_id AS product_id, c1.sku, c2.value AS prdNm, 
c3.value AS product_price, 
c5.value AS category_name, c6.value AS weight, c7.value AS image, 
c8.value AS description, 
c9.value AS price,c11.value AS shipment_type,c12.value AS 
warranty,c13.value AS short_description
FROM catalog_product_entity c1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c2 ON c1.entity_id=c2.entity_id 
AND c2.attribute_id=71
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c3 ON c1.entity_id=c3.entity_id 
AND c3.attribute_id=75
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product c4 ON c1.entity_id=c4.product_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar c5 ON 
c5.entity_id=c4.category_id AND c5.attribute_id=41
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c6 ON c1.entity_id=c6.entity_id 
AND c6.attribute_id=80
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c7 ON c1.entity_id=c7.entity_id 
AND c7.attribute_id=85
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text c8 ON c1.entity_id=c8.entity_id AND 
c8.attribute_id=72
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c9 ON c1.entity_id=c9.entity_id 
AND c9.attribute_id=75
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int c11 ON c1.entity_id=c11.entity_id 
AND 
c11.attribute_id=127
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int c12 ON c1.entity_id=c12.entity_id 
AND 
c12.attribute_id=154
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text c13 ON c1.entity_id=c13.entity_id 
AND c13.attribute_id=73
WHERE c1.entity_id = 190

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$product_id = $row['product_id'];
$product_sku = $row['sku'];
$product_name = $row['prdNm'];
$product_price = $row['product_price'];
$product_category_name = $row['category_name'];
$product_weight = $row['weight'];
$product_image = $row['image'];
$product_description = $row['description'];
$product_price = $row['price'];
$product_shipment_type = $row['shipment_type'];
$product_warranty = $row['warranty'];
$product_short_description = $row['short_description'];

}

';

//removed "br" tag, because if I don't remove "br", it will show me error//

$product_short_description = strip_tags($product_short_description);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.11street.my/rest/prodservices/product",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" 
standalone=\"yes\"?>
<Product>
<selMthdCd>01</selMthdCd>
<dispCtgrNo>4932</dispCtgrNo>
<prdTypCd>01</prdTypCd>
<prdNm>$product_name</prdNm>
<prdStatCd>01</prdStatCd>
<prdWght>$product_weight</prdWght>
<minorSelCnYn>Y</minorSelCnYn>
<prdImage01>$product_image</prdImage01>
<htmlDetail>$product_short_description</htmlDetail>
<advrtStmt>9789792771251</advrtStmt>
<sellerPrdCd>815210</sellerPrdCd>
<selTermUseYn>N</selTermUseYn>
<selPrc>$product_price</selPrc>
<prdSelQty>9999</prdSelQty>
<cuponcheck>Y</cuponcheck>
<dscAmtPercnt>25</dscAmtPercnt>
<cupnDscMthdCd>01</cupnDscMthdCd>
<cupnIssStartDy>13/08/2014</cupnIssStartDy>
<cupnIssEndDy>20/08/2014</cupnIssEndDy>
<cupnUseLmtDyYn>Y</cupnUseLmtDyYn>
<pointYN>Y</pointYN>
<pointValue>100</pointValue>
<spplWyCd>02</spplWyCd>

<selMinLimitQty>3</selMinLimitQty>
<selMinLimitTypCd>01</selMinLimitTypCd>
<selLimitQty>10</selLimitQty>
<selLimitTypCd>02</selLimitTypCd>
<asDetail>-</asDetail>

<dlvMthCd>01</dlvMthCd>
<dlvCstInstBasiCd>01</dlvCstInstBasiCd>
<width>10</width> 
<length>12</length> 
<height>13</height> 
<packageWidth>10</packageWidth> 
<packageLength>12</packageLength> 
<packageHeight>13</packageHeight>
<rtngExchDetail>test sample</rtngExchDetail> 
<suplDtyfrPrdClfCd>04</suplDtyfrPrdClfCd> 
<suplDtyfrPrdClfRate>2.56</suplDtyfrPrdClfRate> 
<productAttributes> 

<attribute> 
<attributeCode>2000005</attributeCode>
<attributeName>Brand</attributeName>
<attributeNo>174034</attributeNo>
<attributeValueList> 
<attributeValue>CHANEL</attributeValue>
<attributeValueCode>2010498</attributeValueCode>
<attributeValueNo>174034</attributeValueNo>
</attributeValueList> 
</attribute> 

<attribute> 
<attributeCode>2009110</attributeCode>
<attributeName>All</attributeName>
<attributeNo>174152</attributeNo>
<attributeValueList> 
<attributeValue>Female</attributeValue>
<attributeValueCode>2010761</attributeValueCode>
<attributeValueNo>174152</attributeValueNo>
</attributeValueList> 
</attribute> 

</productAttributes>
<warrantyType>1</warrantyType> 
<warrantyPeriod>1</warrantyPeriod> 
<packageWeight>1</packageWeight> 
<productFeatures>feature - 1</productFeatures> 
<productFeatures>feature - 2</productFeatures> 

</Product>",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/xml",
"openapikey: sadqwd124312qwrfw353",
 ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

It's just the "html details" element that has a problem, because on the shopping website, `product_short_description` is shown with the two strings combined on the same line like in the image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdIpn.jpg)

What I want instead is for the output of `product_short_description` to have the string separated and shown on two lines, one above the other such as the image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avmkx.jpg)

Hope someone can help me separate the strings in the short product description. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the closing `'` and `;` in your SQL. If it really comes after your `$result` as you posted, then you have a syntax error in `$product_id = $row['product_id'];`. You need a mix of quotation marks or to escape them.

Comment: can run the code, just product_short_description got problem